# Xcode SwiftUI Previews build settings

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcodebuild, xcode-build-settings, swiftui-previews

I am running a pre-build script using scheme. My script has enabled option to provide build settings from target that is being built. This script also gets executed when project is built for SwiftUI Previews. I need to know inside this script if the build that is being run is regular one or for previews. Is there a way to do that and how?

I tried running `export` in the script in both scenarios but it seems that all environment variables are the same in both cases.

Comment: I know there is a flag `XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS` in process info to check while the app is *running* but I need something similar that is available during build

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to check `ENABLE_PREVIEWS` environment variable in scripts.

It is YES for [Build for Previews TARGET]:

[image: demo1]

and NO for [Build for TARGET]:

[image: demo2]

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

Comment: Unfortunately it works only for build (the one in build phases), not for pre-build scripts (those in schemes). I need my script to be ran in the pre-build section.