# Detect if build is triggered from SwiftUI Preview in Build Phases - Run Script

Tags: xcode, swiftui, preview, swiftui-previews, xcode-build-phase

Is there any way to detect if the build was triggered by the SwiftUI Preview from inside Build Phases - Run Script?

I'm using `swiftlint` with `--fix --format`, the problem is when I have the Preview open it sometimes triggers a build, which often changes the file while I'm typing, which then brings up the "keep changes/revert" dialog. Keeping the changes often leads Xcode to crash. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
if buildWasTriggeredBySwiftUIPreview then
    swiftlint
else 
    swiftlint --fix --format && swiftlint
fi
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70802531/5133585) answer your question? It seems like you can just check an environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sweeper, this works:

```
if [ "${ENABLE_PREVIEWS}" = "YES" ]; then 
    swiftlint
else 
    swiftlint --fix --format && swiftlint  
fi
```